# Spring : Autowire

Tags: spring

If I initialize one object manually ,inside that class I have autowired some of the other classes , Does spring creates and instances of Autowired objects ?

Example :

```
Class A {
@Autowired 
B b;
}

Class main {
main(){
A a = new A();
//Does spring initialize B class also automatically(Autowired)?
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Class A by itself has to be managed by spring as well as class B

In general Autowiring works only for classes that are managed by spring

Comment: Ok .Thank you  Mark :)